# Combining values of Shannon Entropy

Tags: entropy

I have a set of n variables. Each of these variables an be one of a finite number, m, of values. The number of values is different for each variable and independent. From [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy#Definition) I can calculate the Shannon Entropy of any single one of these variables, assuming I know the probability of each value occurring (which I do). Up to here I'm fine I believe.

What I don't understand is how I can then combine the values I would calculate across all the variables. For example lets say I have 2 variables (n=2). The Shannon entropy of variable 1 might be 0.6, and the value for variable 2 might be 0.8. How do I then combine these values to get the Shannon entropy of the system? Is it addition (eg 1.4 in this case), multiplication (0.48) or some more complicated function? I'm concerned that I am misinterpreting what the Shannon entropy is.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need more information in order to answer this question. What, exactly, does it mean to "have" two variables?  What is the "system"?

Comment: @whuber, sorry for not including enough information. The two variables are positions of objects on a grid. The grid is of finite size, and each object can only be in a given subset of squares on the grid. Is that enough information?

Comment: I still don't follow.  What is the *new* variable whose entropy you wish to determine and how exactly is it related to the old variables?

Comment: @whuber there isn't a new variable. I was asking how one might find the total entropy of a system if the entropy of the subsystem components is known. Aaron has answered that I can simply add the values together!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If I can improve the question please let me know.

Comment: @whuber, this has been voted to close, but it has an upvoted & accepted answer. Do you think it is clear enough now?

Comment: Aaron's answer makes an assumption that appears to conflict with the description, which is that the objects "can only be in a given subset": that suggests *lack* of independence.  I downvoted this question because, despite repeated requests for clarification, it never was clarified and as such now has an accepted answer that very well could be incorrect. I hope that the downvote might alert future readers to the potential for misinterpreting this thread (cc @gung).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are independent you can add the entropies together to get the joint entropy.